# Matlab optimization stopping criteria

Tags: matlab, optimization, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve a system of 12 equations in Matlab. Because I have constraints on the minimum and maximum values of the variables I use lsqnonlin rather than fsolve. However, I would like the optimizer to stop once the output (sum of squared deviations from the point where each equation holds) is sufficiently close to zero. Is there a way to specify such a stopping criterion?

The standard stopping criteria are about comparing the change in the output value compared to previous iteration but this is less relevant for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [fmincon](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) function to solve the equations with [bounded constraints](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busowz9-1).

Because you have not provided anything, follow the example provided by MATLAB:

```
fun = @(x)1+x(1)/(1+x(2)) - 3*x(1)*x(2) + x(2)*(1+x(1)); % objective function
lb = [0,0]; % lower bounds
ub = [1,2]; % upper bounds
x0 = (lb + ub)/2; % initial estimate
x = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub)
```

This specifies the range `0<x(1)<1` and `0<x(2)<2` for the variables.

The fmincon function also lets you [change the default options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#busow0u-1_1). To specify the tolerance for the output, set it:

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter','FunctionTolerance',1e-10);
```

This sets fmincon options to have iterative display, and to have a FunctionTolerance of 1e-10. Call the fmincon function with these nonstandard options:

```
x = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],options)
```